# How to update latitude and longitude of google map when drapg the polygon

Tags: javascript

I am using Geo-fence of google map i have drown polygon and render the map when i drag the polygon i will update wrong direction as showing below image

polygon is editable not drag

all data coming from database when drag i want to update that point only not whole map

only the drag point should be update

how can i updated the polygon while dragging any body help thanks in advance

this is polygon map before drag and refresh

http://prntscr.com/mry00e

after drag and refresh the polygon point

http://prntscr.com/mry0sk

which i do not want

this is my code

```
var poly;
var map;

function initMap() 
{
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: 7,
       draggable: true,
       // Center the map on Islamabad, Pakistan.
       center: {lat: 33.6844, lng: 73.0479},
   });

   /* shaded polyline inside area*/
   poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
       strokeColor: "#FF0000",
       strokeOpacity: 0.8,
       strokeWeight: 2,
       fillColor: "#FF0000",
       fillOpacity: 0.35,
       map: map,
       editable: true,
       geodesic: false
   });

   $.ajax({
     url: 'show-data',
     type: 'GET',
   })
   .done(function(res) 
   {

       $.each(res, function(i, val)
       {
           var latval = val.lat;
           var lngval = val.lng;
           if(lngval != '')
           {
               renderMap(latval, lngval);
               createMarker(latval, lngval);

           }
       });

   })
   .fail(function() 
   {
       console.log("error");
   });

   poly.getPath().addListener('set_at', function(e)
   {
       var latitude = poly.getPath().getAt(e);
       var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude.lat(), latitude.lng());
       displayCoordinates(latlng);
   });

 /* Map Render here */
   function renderMap(latval, lngval)
   {
       var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latval, lngval);
       var path = poly.getPath();
       path.push(latlng);
   }

   poly.setMap(map);


 // Add a listener for the click event
   map.addListener('click', addLatLng);

} 

/* Draw Marker */
function createMarker(latval, lngval)
{
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latval, lngval);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: latlng,
       map: map,
       flat: true,
       title: 'Latitude',
       //draggable: true,
       raiseOnDrag: false,
       icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
   });
}


/* Display Coordinates */
function displayCoordinates(pnt) 
{
   var lat = pnt.lat();
   var lng = pnt.lng();
   $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
   });

 /* Ajax Request to post data to database */
   $.ajax({
     url: 'geofence',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {lat: lat,lng: lng},
   })
   .done(function() 
   {
       console.log("success");
   })
   .fail(function() 
   {
       console.log("error");
   })
}
```

Comment: So when you drag it, the polygon surface increased and it display well? And when you refresh, the changes you POST to database are incorrect?

Comment: I don't know how you're handling your polygon points(Lat/Lon) in your Backend Server, but I don't see you pass any unique reference value to the point that is being modified. So that you probably push an additional point so that your Polygon pass to 4 Points to 5, 6, 7 Points, each time you set it to a new position. Each point should have an attached polygon-point-id to make sure you're updating only for example `polygon-point-4`.

Comment: do you have duplicates point in your polygon which is fetched from server I mean your first point and your last point is equal?

Comment: every value is seprate fist and last

Comment: when drag it it looks better but the point store to database is incorrect

Comment: every polygon has unique latitude. when drag it expends from last and first points